# Azure ML endpoint 404 error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

An Azure Data Factory pipeline for updating a trained ML model returns this error:

```
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /workspaces/xxxx/webservices/xxxx/endpoints/update

Diagnostic details: job ID xxxx. Endpoint https://services.azureml.net/workspaces/xxxx/webservices/xxxx/endpoints/update.
```

I don't even want to think about why it returned a HTML document...
I am 100% sure that the endpoint exists and the key provided is correct.
So what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and creating the endpoint again fixed it.

Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your endpoint, seems you are using a CLASSIC azure machine learning web service, right? If so, you can copy paste your PATCH endpoint from the web service management portal: https://services.azureml.net/classicWebservices/ .

Usually its format is like this way:
https://management.azureml.net/workspaces/xxxxx/webservices/xxxxx/endpoints/forupdate

Comment: That's exactly what I did. This is the "Requested URL" mentioned above. I quadruple checked.

Comment: The host of your endpoint seems not a valid format. Could you please provide your runid or detailed payload for further troubleshooting?

Comment: Do you mean the "xxxx"? I removed the ID's for privacy reasons.

Comment: No, I mean the host. It usually begins with "https://management.azureml.net", but yours begins with "https://services.azureml.net". Seems it's not a valid patch endpoint.